# Copying Formulas to Show

Tags: openoffice-calc

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to copy a page of formulas to a text document (final target will be scribus - but this is irrelevant). What I'm wanting is to copy the actual formulas - create a table containing the formulas and not, instead, their values.

I've looked through Paste Special to try to come to a solution, but can't seem to find one. Has anybody successfully done this, or does anybody know how to successfully do this?

Lachlan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toggle on OOo Calc `Tools > Options > OpenOffice.orgCalc > View > Display > Formulas`. Then your cut&paste will be copying the text of the formulas rather than the results. Toggle off that `Display > Formulas` for normal operations.

Ref http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2350/openoffice_org_calc_show_formulas/

Comment: Accepted - with one reservation. Works with Unformatted Text output, but not the formatted ones. But works for my needs - thanks